# How to config yii2 urlManager rules?

Tags: yii2

Here is Yii2 code in main.php:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'suffix' => '.html',
            'rules' => [
                // site controller
                '' => 'site/index',
                'contact_us' => 'site/contact',
            // sitemap controller
              'sitemap' => 'sitemap/index'
            ]
```

And url in browser is:
 + Site controller: 
   - http://localhost/neko/
   - http://localhost/neko/contact_us.html
 + Sitemap controller:
   - http://localhost/neko/sitemap/index.html

How to I configure my sitemap controller to http://localhost/neko/sitemap.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array configuration for `sitemap.xml`, like that:

```
'rules' => [
    // site controller
    '' => 'site/index',
    'contact_us' => 'site/contact',
    // sitemap controller
    [
        'pattern' => 'sitemap',
        'route' => 'sitemap/index',
        'suffix' => '.xml',
    ],
],
```

See [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules).

Comment: Hi vitalik, when I add ['pattern' => 'sitemap', 'route' => 'sitemap/index', 'suffix' => '.xml'], I met problem. The exception: 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' in ...SitemapController.php